# Writing inputstream to file - no file found

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write inputstream to a file, but it never gets written on disk, I just get the error file doesnt exist. The file I open is a drawable icluded in the project, I would like to save it to sd card. This is what I have so far:

```
File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/tester");
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.test);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(storagePath, "test.png"));
    byte buffer[] = new byte[900];
    int len;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0)
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    out.close();
    inputStream.close();
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is why it doesn't write the file to sd card with the code given. I can't find any errors or reason why it shouldnt work...

Comment: Well perhaps you should invoke `out.flush()` before `out.close()`.

Comment: Do you have the right permissions declared in the manifest? mainly write external storage.

Comment: Yes, I have both, write and read...

Comment: He shouldn't need to `flush` the stream; `close` implies it. Badr, have you tried printing out the `storagePath` and making sure it's pointing where you think? You'd get an `IOException`, not a missing file, if it weren't getting created.

Comment: This is my IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/tester/test.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) @chrylis

Comment: @BadrHari Okay, that's very different from the impression your question gave; always, always post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tester` directory doesn't exist. Check for it and create it if necessary before opening your `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: You are correct, I was silly, for some reason I thought the first line will create the di automatically myself, so basically I added storagePath.mkdirs(); as second line.